# Generate initial database migration script from existing schema

Tags: sql-server, database, version-control, migratordotnet

I have a huge pre-existing database that I'd like to bring under version control using [Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) for migration scripts and I don't like keeping the MDF file around just for the existing schema.

How can I generate an initial migration script (`Migration` class) for Migrator.NET from the existing schema that I can use to build the schema from scratch and use incremental builds onwards?

Answer (score 1):

According to this link http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/wiki/WritingMigrations you can do this:

```
Migrator.Console.exe SqlServer "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection?=True" MyMigrations.dll -dump "c:\temp\dump.cs"
```